# How can I run multiple animations at the same time

Tags: anime.js

I am trying to run 2 Animations at the same time. But they should be in **different timelines**. 
One div should be change the color (backgroundColor to 'ff0000') and an other 
div should disappear (opacity to 0)

How can I do that only with anime.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make two separated [Timelines](https://animejs.com/documentation/#timelineBasics)